# Can I use Javascript to stream audio sound from Pepper's microphone using ALAudioDevice (setClientPreferences and then subscribe)?

Tags: javascript, audio, streaming, subscribe, pepper

I was successfully streaming audio sound from Pepper's microphone to my notebook using python:

```
 class SoundReceiverModule(naoqi.ALModule):
    .......
    def start( self ):
        audio = naoqi.ALProxy( "ALAudioDevice", self.strNaoIp, 9559 );
        nNbrChannelFlag = 3; 
        nDeinterleave = 0;
        nSampleRate = 48000;
        audio.setClientPreferences( self.getName(),  nSampleRate, nNbrChannelFlag, nDeinterleave ); 
        audio.subscribe( self.getName() );  

    def processRemote( self, nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel, aTimeStamp, buffer ):
        aSoundDataInterlaced = np.fromstring( str(buffer), dtype=np.int16 );
        aSoundData = np.reshape( aSoundDataInterlaced, (nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel), 'F' );
    .......
```

However, when I do it using Javascript, no signal was generated after subscribing the ALAudioDevice.  Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some Javascript code you could add - that'd make it easier for us to fix up?

Comment: Below is one of my tried codes for achieving the goal:

`const audioCapture = () => {
 nNbrChannelFlag = 3; 
 nDeinterleave = 0;
 nSampleRate = 48000;
 moduleName='audiocapture';
 pepperCon.ALAudioDevice.setClientPreferences( 
  moduleName,
  nSampleRate, 
  nNbrChannelFlag, 
  nDeinterleave 
 );
 results1 = pepperCon.ALAudioDevice.subscribe(moduleName);
 console.log(result1);
 processRemote(results1);
}`

The console.log output:

{done: ƒ, fail: ƒ, always: ƒ, progress: ƒ, _then: ƒ, …}

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this at the moment sorry, but I hope this serves as a starting point. Please let me know if this works, or if not and you get any errors.

```js
class SoundReceiverModule {
    constructor(){
    }
    processRemote(nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel, buffer, timeStamp){
        console.log(buffer)
    }
}

const channels = 3;
const deinterleaved = 0;
const sampleRate = 48000;
const moduleName = SoundReceiverModule.name;

// with /libs/qimessaging/2/qimessaging.js included
QiSession.connect(function (session) {
    session.service("ALAudioDevice").then(function (ALAudioDevice) {
        ALAudioDevice.setClientPreferences(moduleName, sampleRate, channels, deinterleaved);
        ALAudioDevice.subscribe(moduleName);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.                                                                                        
An error occurred when running the script: qimessaging.js:71 Uncaught (in promise)  ALProxy::ALProxy  Can't find service: SoundReceiverModule

Comment: The module needs to extend the ALModule class, but I'm unsure how exactly to reference it through the javascript APIs. Can you try changing the first line to `class SoundReceiverModule extends ALModule{`? If that doesn't work, can you run the following? `QiSession.connect(function (session) {` `session.service("ALAudioDevice").then(function (ALAudioDevice) {` `console.log(ALAudioDevice.constructor.name);` `console.log(ALAudioDevice.super.constructor.name);` `});` `});`

Comment: 'extends ALModule' not worked;

`console.log(ALAudioDevice.constructor.name) : object;`

`console.log(ALAudioDevice.super.constructor.name) : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined`

Comment: Try `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(ALAudioDevice.constructor).name)` then `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(ALAudioDevice.constructor)).name)` and so on... (to find what classes ALAudioDevice is an instance of - hopefully this will let us find ALModule). Also try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(session)` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ALAudioDevice)`.

Comment: console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(ALAudioDevice.constructor).name):
`output nothing`
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(ALAudioDevice.constructor)).name):
`undefined`
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(session)):
`(17) ["qiSession", "ALTextToSpeechE", "ALTextToSpeechC", "ALSpeechRecognition", "ALAudioDevice", "ALMotion", "ALRobotPosture", "ALTabletService", "ALSystem", "ALBasicAwareness", "ALBackgroundMovement", "ALBehavior", "ALVideoDevice", "ALBattery", "ALAutonomousBlinking", "ALSpeakingMovement", "ALListeningMovement"]`

Comment: console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ALAudioDevice)):
`(69) ["__MetaObject", "registerEvent", "unregisterEvent", "metaObject", "terminate", "property", "setProperty", "properties", "registerEventWithSignature", "isStatsEnabled", "enableStats", "stats", "clearStats", "isTraceEnabled", "enableTrace", "exit", "__pCall", "pCall", "version", "ping", "getMethodList", "getMethodHelp", "getModuleHelp", "wait", "isRunning", "stop", "getBrokerName", "getUsage", "subscribe", "unsubscribe", "sendLocalBufferToOutput", "sendRemoteBufferToOutput", "setFileAsInput", "setParameter", "getParameter",  .....]`

Comment: Can you access ALModule through `session`? 
`QiSession.connect(function (session) {`
`session.service("ALModule").then(function (ALModule) {`
`console.log(ALModule);`
`});`
`});`

Comment: Cannot be connected or accessed when replacing 'ALAudioDevice' with 'ALModule'.

Comment: How can I rewrite the following python codes with javascript?
`class SoundReceiverModule(naoqi.ALModule):
    def __init__( self, strModuleName, strNaoIp ):
            naoqi.ALModule.__init__(self, strModuleName );
            self.BIND_PYTHON( self.getName(),"callback" );`

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that this "says": `class SoundReceiverModule extends naoqi.ALModule`, to actually make the new class `SoundReceiverModule` a module. Otherwise we get the error we got at the start: `ALProxy Can't find service: SoundReceiverModule` - ALProxy searches the modules on Pepper to find `ALSoundReceiverModule` but it can't because we never made it a module. The issue is I don't know how to access `ALModule` through the javascript APIs. I'll keep thinking of possibilities. Or there might be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach I'll add as an alternate answer because it's more of a workaround. The idea is to use the SoundReceiverModule in Python like you have, then publish the sound data in an event which can be received by the javascript APIs. We will pass this data through the new ALMemory event, `sound-data-processed`.

You'll need to make a Choregraphe app that looks like this. Note that the web page must be stored as `html/index.html`.

[image]

In index.html put the following. Of course, you can move this code to a separate .js file and include it in the html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>SoundReceiverModuleTest</title>
</head>

<body style="background: black;">
    <script src="/libs/qimessaging/2/qimessaging.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        QiSession.connect(function (session) {
            session.service("ALMemory").then(function (ALMemory) {
                ALMemory.subscriber("sound-data-processed").then(function (subscriber){
                    subscriber.signal.connect(function (data){
                        // here is the sound data from the Python event
                        // alert will show it on Pepper's tablet screen
                        alert(data);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've slightly modified the example Python audio module from the docs [here](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/other-tutorials/python-sdk-tutorials/python-sdk-examples-1-0). You can run it from an external computer (if you have the python qi sdk installed) like so:

```sh
python audio_module.py --ip <nao-ip>
```

Where `audio_module.py` is how I've saved the below file, and `<nao-ip>` is the IP address of your Pepper on the same network as your computer.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-

"""Example: Get Signal from Front Microphone & Calculate its rms Power"""


import qi
import argparse
import sys
import time
import numpy as np


class SoundProcessingModule(object):
    """
    A simple get signal from the front microphone of Nao & calculate its rms power.
    It requires numpy.
    """

    def __init__( self, app):
        """
        Initialise services and variables.
        """
        super(SoundProcessingModule, self).__init__()
        app.start()
        session = app.session

        # Get the service ALAudioDevice.
        self.audio_service = session.service("ALAudioDevice")
        self.memory_service = session.service('ALMemory')
        self.isProcessingDone = False
        self.nbOfFramesToProcess = 20
        self.framesCount=0
        self.micFront = []
        self.module_name = "SoundProcessingModule"

    def startProcessing(self):
        """
        Start processing
        """
        # ask for the front microphone signal sampled at 16kHz
        # if you want the 4 channels call setClientPreferences(self.module_name, 48000, 0, 0)
        self.audio_service.setClientPreferences(self.module_name, 16000, 3, 0)
        self.audio_service.subscribe(self.module_name)

        while self.isProcessingDone == False:
            time.sleep(1)

        self.audio_service.unsubscribe(self.module_name)

    def processRemote(self, nbOfChannels, nbOfSamplesByChannel, timeStamp, inputBuffer):
        """
        Publish sound data to ALMemory event.
        """
        self.framesCount = self.framesCount + 1

        if (self.framesCount <= self.nbOfFramesToProcess):
            # convert inputBuffer to signed integer as it is interpreted as a string by python
            soundData = self.convertStr2SignedInt(inputBuffer)
            # send the data to an ALMemory event that can be read in Javascript
            self.memory_service.raise_event('sound-data-processed', soundData)
        else :
            self.isProcessingDone=True

    def convertStr2SignedInt(self, data) :
        """
        This function takes a string containing 16 bits little endian sound
        samples as input and returns a vector containing the 16 bits sound
        samples values converted between -1 and 1.
        """
        signedData=[]
        ind=0;
        for i in range (0,len(data)/2) :
            signedData.append(data[ind]+data[ind+1]*256)
            ind=ind+2

        for i in range (0,len(signedData)) :
            if signedData[i]>=32768 :
                signedData[i]=signedData[i]-65536

        for i in range (0,len(signedData)) :
            signedData[i]=signedData[i]/32768.0

        return signedData


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--ip", type=str, default="127.0.0.1",
                        help="Robot IP address. On robot or Local Naoqi: use '127.0.0.1'.")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=9559,
                        help="Naoqi port number")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        # Initialize qi framework.
        connection_url = "tcp://" + args.ip + ":" + str(args.port)
        app = qi.Application(["SoundProcessingModule", "--qi-url=" + connection_url])
    except RuntimeError:
        print ("Can't connect to Naoqi at ip \"" + args.ip + "\" on port " + str(args.port) +".\n"
               "Please check your script arguments. Run with -h option for help.")
        sys.exit(1)
    MySoundProcessingModule = SoundProcessingModule(app)
    app.session.registerService("SoundProcessingModule", MySoundProcessingModule)
    MySoundProcessingModule.startProcessing()
```

Comment: Again, I haven't been able to actually test this sorry, so let me know if you experience any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Error generated when the choregraphe was run:

`[ERROR] behavior.box :_safeCallOfUserMethod:125 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11662506592:/ALSoundDevice_1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/aldebaran/lib/python2.7/site-packages/albehavior.py", line 115, in _safeCallOfUserMethod     func()   File "<string>", line 31, in onUnload   File "/opt/aldebaran/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ialbehavior.py", line 108, in <lambda>     __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, behavior, name)   File "/opt/aldebaran/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ialbehavior.py", line 57, in _swig_getattr     raise AttributeError(name) AttributeError: soundReceiver   [ERROR] behavior.box :_safeCallOfUserMethod:125 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11662506592:/ALSoundDevice_1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/aldebaran/lib/python2.7/site-packages/albehavior.py", line 115, in _safeCallOfUserMethod     func()   File "<string>", line 34, in onInput_onStart TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`  
[image: Error on running the choregraphe]

However, when I added an input name to self.soundReceiver = SoundReceiverModule(**'SoundReceiver'**), then pepper's shoulder leds turned yellow (then red) after running the choregraphe and no signal was received on browsing the webpage http://pepper-ip/apps/....

Comment: I've edited the code in my answer for the Python box so that you don't need to explicitly initialise it - I hope that will help. If Pepper's shoulder lights go yellow and red, you can press the chest button to hear what errors or warnings were raised.

Comment: Pepper went into 'fatal error' state and no response came from pressing the chest button.   Pepper need to hard reboot for coming to work properly.

Comment: For your previous suggested Choregraphe box, it will not generate error message when I add broker to the class as follow:
`class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self)
        self.myBroker = naoqi.ALBroker("myBroker","0.0.0.0", 8000, '192.168.24.201', 9559)`
However, still no data flow (no message alert) will be generated on pepper tablet (only black screen as expected).  But for this version of Choregraphe, the broker was not functioned then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was partly solved:
[image]

```
import numpy as np
class SoundReceiverModule(ALModule):
    def __init__( self, strModuleName, strNaoIp ):
        try:
            ALModule.__init__(self, strModuleName )
            self.BIND_PYTHON( self.getName(), "callback" )
            self.strNaoIp = strNaoIp
        except BaseException, err:
            print( "loading error: %s" % str(err) )
    
        def __del__( self ):
            print( "SoundReceiverModule.__del__: cleaning everything" );
            self.stop();        

    def start(self):
        audio = ALProxy("ALAudioDevice", self.strNaoIp, 9559)
        nNbrChannelFlag = 3
        nDeinterleave = 0
        nSampleRate = 48000
        audio.setClientPreferences(self.getName(),  nSampleRate, nNbrChannelFlag, nDeinterleave)
        audio.subscribe(self.getName())

    def stop(self):
        audio = ALProxy("ALAudioDevice", self.strNaoIp, 9559)
        audio.unsubscribe(self.getName())

    def processRemote(self, nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel, aTimeStamp, buffer):
        self.memory = ALProxy("ALMemory") 
        aSoundDataInterlaced = np.fromstring(str(buffer), dtype=np.int16)
        aSoundData = np.reshape(aSoundDataInterlaced, (nbOfChannels, nbrOfSamplesByChannel), 'F')
        self.memory.raiseEvent('sound-data-processed', aSoundData)

class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self)
        self.myBroker = ALBroker("myBroker", "0.0.0.0", 0, "192.168.24.201", 9559)

    def onLoad(self):   
        #put initialization code here
        pass

    def onUnload(self):
        #put clean-up code here
        SoundReceiver.stop()

    def onInput_onStart(self):
        global SoundReceiver
        SoundReceiver = SoundReceiverModule("SoundReceiver", "192.168.24.201")
        SoundReceiver.start()

    def onInput_onStop(self):
        self.myBroker.shutdown()
        self.onUnload() 
        
    def onStopped():    
        self.onStopped()
```

However, the unsolved problem is 'no sound data streamed from subscribing the SoundReceiver'.

Comment: Maybe `SoundReceiver = SoundReceiverModule("SoundReceiver", "192.168.24.201")` should be `SoundReceiver = SoundReceiverModule("SoundReceiverModule", "192.168.24.201")`. But perhaps a better idea is just to use your existing python code you run offboard (not in Choregraphe) - then to do the same publishing the sound data to ALMemory and subscribing to this in your JS.

Comment: It should be "SoundReceiver" otherwise processRemote() will not be triggered.  Your suggestion of running python code offboard is what I wanted to do originally but I didn't know how to run it within javascripts?

Comment: Actually I want to display what pepper see with its camera on a web browser using javascript.  It was already done but with no audio sound captured.  So what I really need now is some scripts that can be embedded in the existing javascript codes so that users can easily manage the view (with sound) from remote places.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you wish to display the video and audio on the browser on Pepper's tablet? Or on a different computer on the same wifi network as Pepper? Or on a different computer on a different network?

Comment: I've edited the Choregraphe workaround answer to show how to run the javascript webapp on Pepper's tablet browser, while running the python audio module offboard. Let me know how that goes for you. If it works, it's fairly straightforward to run the JS code in an external browser too.

Comment: Again, thanks Dominic.  I wish to make it appear on web browser of a PC running windows 10.  What the final product I really needed is a folder with only html, js, css and some library files for some people who do not know python and its required running environment.  This is also the main reason why I want the coding to be written with javascript or it can be executed automatically in windows without the need of other installations.

Comment: If the PC is on the same network as Pepper this is straightforward. Follow the answer I posted (ie. run the python code offboard), but instead of running the app with the JS APIs on Pepper, you can access the HTML page through your computer's browser. Just enter `<pepper-ip>/apps/<id-of-your-app>/index.html` in your browser address bar. Where `<pepper-ip>` is the IP of your robot, and `<id-of-your-app>` is the ID of the app you assigned in Choregraphe (if you just press play to load the app in Choregraphe, it will be `.lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior` for example).

Comment: Surely the users' PCs are on the same network as their own Peppers and they all know how to access pepper tablet webpage with IP and application id.  It is not the problem.  The main point is that they do not know how to run the python code offboard and their PCs will surely not equipped with the necessary environment to run the python code.

Comment: Another important point is that the showing of what pepper see and hear is only one of the functions of the final product. It will only be displayed on a small area of the main page when a button is clicked while other function icons, buttons, menus and inputs occupy the spaces in other regions. The layout is important and will not be changed at this moment.

Comment: In this case your code here is the easiest starting point for doing it in Choregraphe. Can you add `self.logger.info(aSoundData)` into `processRemote` and check the logs to see if sound data is actually being processed here? Maybe `self.memory = ALProxy("ALMemory")` should go in `start`. Or maybe converting from a string buffer to int is throwing an error? Are you repeatedly getting the null alert in javascript, like the event is being triggered but there's no data? Or is the event not triggered at all?

Comment: If you package the python code with choregraphe like this, the users can then just install this app and run it via the app launcher (with or without Pepper's tablet display). Then access the html page from their browsers.

Comment: That part of the problem was solved with `processRemote` functioned properly (see above edited diagram) . Just use the previously displayed choregraphe but `aSoundData` in `self.memory.raiseEvent('sound-data-processed', aSoundData)` was replaced with `aSoundData[0].tolist() `. The next thing I have to do is writing javascript code for decoding the audio data and playing them in the remote PC's browser.

Comment: Ok, good to know. In that case I'd consider this question not so much answered as "worked around". But if you encounter any issues in your future work it'd be best if you make a new question specific to them.

Comment: Yes, the question was not solved completely but I think one of the solution is coming closer and closer.  @Dominic Anyway, thank you for your help and useful suggestions.